# Consequence of definition of Boolean algebra

Tags: logic

The following is from *Introduction to Mathematical Logic, Sixth Edition* by Mendelson, Elliott

Let $B$ be a nonempty set, $f$ a function from $B$ into $B,$ and $g$ a function from
$B^2$ into $B.$ Write $x'$ for $f(x)$ and $x \cap y$ for $g(x, y).$ Then $〈B, f, g〉$ is called a Boolean
algebra if $B$ contains at least two elements and the following conditions are
satisfied:

(1) $x \cap y = y \cap x$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $B.$

(2) $(x\cap y)\cap z = x \cap (y\cap z)$ for all $x,y,z$ in $B.$

(3) $x\cap y' = z\cap z'$ if and only if $x\cap y = x$ for all $x,y,z$ in $B.$

> **Question : Prove that $z\cap z' = w\cap w'$ for any $w$ and $z$ in $B.$**

My attempt :

Let $w\in B.$

It appears that if $w=x$ and $w=y$ in $(3)$ then what I want to show reduces to showing that $w\cap w = w$ for any $w\in B.$

I tried assuming that $w\cap w \ne w$ to bring forth a contradiction but couldn't get anywhere.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking $x=y=z=w$ in $(3)$, we have $w\cap w'=w\cap w'$ iff $w\cap w=w$; since it’s certainly true that $w\cap w'=w\cap w'$, it must be true that $w\cap w=w$.